# Dataframes update?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ROU': ['A', 'A', 'A'],'Pre': ['3.0.0.0', '4.0.0.0', '3.0.0.0'],'A_s': ['1', '2', '1000']})
```

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'ROU': ['A', 'A'],'Pre': ['3.0.0.0','4.0.0.0'],'A_s': ['5', '40']})
```

Is it possible to modify the first Data frame to become

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ROU': ['A', 'A', 'A'],'Pre': ['3.0.0.0', '4.0.0.0', '3.0.0.0'],'A_s': ['1', '40', '5']})
```

Which means to find matching values (like in an inner join) columns between the two data frames and then change only the last occurrence of each match with the new value and keep the other occurrences the same

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot control values in 3rd column this solution should be enough and work properly:

```py
df['A_s'][-len(new_df['A_s']):] = new_df['A_s'][::-1]
```

In the case `[::-1]` is probably completely optional.

Comment: This line does what I want partially because the value of the third column of the first row became Nan however I want it to be the same :
```
  ROU      Pre  A_s
```
```
0   A  3.0.0.0  NaN
```
```
1   A  4.0.0.0    2
```
```
2   A  3.0.0.0  500

Comment: No actually if I shuffle the order of the values of the second column the output is wrong

Comment: Why are you shuffeling the column values?

Comment: Because I cannot control the order of those values of that column

Comment: I gave a brief example of what I want but my second DF is completely random when it comes to the order of the values that's why I said I must do something like an inner join between the two DFs and then do the changes